# Passing portal location down to children

Tags: reactjs

I want to use React Portals (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). The location where a portal should render is also rendered by React. There is a component that renders the portal "placeholder" (so to call it) and must pass it down to its children so that one (or many) of them can `ReactDOM.createPortal`.

**Is there a recommended way for doing so?**

I am using refs to capture the portal placeholder. On the first render the children get `null` in the prop they are expecting. I am also checking if it's null on the children before trying to render the portal. I am NOT storing the ref in the state. Sometimes it seems that acquiring the ref causes a prop change in the children, sometimes it just doesn't work.

If I try to `document.getElementById` directly on the children (by hardcoding the id of the placeholder in the parent component) it doesn't work because on the first render the DOM doesn't know about that element.

**EDIT: Added code example**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render {
        return (
            <div>
                <div ref={ref => this.portalContainer = ref}/>
                <SomeChild renderYourPortalHere={this.portalContainer}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const SomeChild = props => (
    props.renderYourPortalHere
        ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<IrrelevantOtherComponent/>, props.renderYourPortalHere)
        : null;
)
```

Comment: Not sure of the recommended way but this can be done by polling the DOM to check if the element with id is rendered or not in a setTimeout that would either return the element or setTimeout again. Once the element is in the DOM, you can render the portal.

Comment: @Surender Thx. I have the feeling that rendering the portal placeholder with react is out of the scope of portals itself, unless you store the placeholder ref in the state of the renderer.

Comment: Do you have some code I can take a look at?